# VBA - Query with multiple AND statement not working

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I'm having a hard time trying to gather data from an Oracle DB. I've managed to get the connection going, so the problem lies within the query. At the moment the query dont return anything, and neither VBA complains about it.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Connect_XXXX()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim myQuery As ADODB.Command
Set myQuery = New ADODB.Command


conn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
          "Data Source=XXXX;" & _
          "User Id=YYYY;" & _
          "Password=ZZZZ"

myQuery.ActiveConnection = conn

myQuery.CommandText = "SELECT sta.index_id, sta.index_action as Action, sta.ticker, sta.company, sta.announcement_date as A_Date, sta.announcement_time as A_Time, " & _
                        "sta.effective_date as E_Date, dyn.index_supply_demand as BS_Shares, dyn.net_index_supply_demand as Net_BS_Shares, dyn.est_funding_trade as BS_Value, " & _
                        "dyn.trade_adv_perc/100 as Days_to_Trade, dyn.pre_index_weight/100 as Wgt_Old, dyn.post_index_weight/100 as Wgt_New, dyn.net_index_weight/100 as Wgt_Chg, " & _
                        "dyn.pre_est_index_holdings as Index_Hldgs_Old, dyn.post_est_index_holdings as Index_Hldgs_New, dyn.net_est_index_holdings as Index_Hldgs_Chg, sta.index_action_details as Details " & _
                        "FROM index_analysis.eq_index_actions_dyn dyn, index_analysis.eq_index_actions_static sta " & _
                        "WHERE (sta.action_id = dyn.action_id) AND (sta.announcement_date=dyn.price_date) AND (sta.announcement_date >= '01-January-2015') AND (sta.announcement_date <= '30-January-2015') " & _
                        "ORDER by sta.index_id,sta.announcement_date"



Set rs = myQuery.Execute

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

I've played around with the query a lot, and I've been able to get some results by removing some of the AND statements after the WHERE and trying with fewer fields on the SELECT statement, but I need them all in order for this results to work for me. The weird thing is that if I run the same query in a problem like Oracle Sql Developer (after connecting to the DB) it shows the results that I want. I could really use some help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to hard-code the date range, assuming `announcement_date` is a `date`, you'd want to compare against dates, not strings.  You can use `to_date` with an explicit format mask to convert a string to a date,

```
sta.announcement_date >= to_date( '01-January-2015', 'DD-Month-YYYY')
```

or you can use a date literal which always has the format YYYY-MM-DD

```
sta.announcement_date >= date '2015-01-01'
```

My guess is that your code seems to work in SQL Developer because you happen to have configured your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to be 'DD-Month-YYYY' in SQL Developer.

In reality, you should really be using bind variables rather than hard-coding things like the date range.  Assuming you bind a date value, the conversion (if any) from a string to a date would happen in VB and wouldn't depend on your session's NLS settings.  There are also performance and security reasons to prefer bind variables.